# Install font without messing up firefox

Tags: 18.04, gnome, firefox, libreoffice, fonts

I installed the Roboto font to be able to use it in LibreOffice:

```
mv ~/Downloads/Roboto ~/.fonts/
```

This works fine, the font can be used in LibreOffice as intended. However, for some reason firefox now thinks that it should use "Roboto Black" as the default font for all websites that rely on `"font-family: system-ui;"`, making them essentially unreadable (this affects many "major" websites, like twitter, linkedin, etc)

1. Why does firefox think it should use this particular font? The font is not referenced in the [firefox settings (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyoS8.png) and there are other fonts installed in `~/.fonts/`, so why this one?
2. [Gnome Tweaks (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8kct.png) doesn't mention Roboto at all
3. How can I revert this behaviour, but still keep using the Roboto font in LibreOffice?

Ubuntu 18.04, Firefox 68.0.1 installed via apt repo (no snaps).

Comment: I would try to remove them from `~/.fonts` and install the `fonts-roboto` package from the Ubuntu archive instead. I think that will change the `fontconfig` priority order to your liking.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thank you, this works - but it's more a workaround than a solution. I will probably have the same issue again as soon as I install the next font (and not all fonts are available as a .deb) - any idea what is happening here or how to prevent this behaviour?